# RejectedExecutionException in ScheduledFutureTask in Spring WebApp after ContextRefreshed

Tags: java, spring

I'm using this code to Schedule a Task in my Java 8 Spring WebApp:

In a @Controller;

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterContextRefreshed() {

    ScheduledFuture<?> countdown = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                Execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         
        }}, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    while (!countdown.isDone()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    scheduler.shutdown();
}
```

When the App starts, the `Execute()` method gets called 10 seconds after startup with no errors, but after it completes I get the following stack trace:

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@52518e6[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@759546c8[Wrapped task = com.mycompany.myproject.service.LoadService$1@4871ba3f]] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@798daafa[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2055)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:825)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:340)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:562)

Any ideas why I get this exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify this:

```
public class DeleteMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSomethingAfterContextRefreshed();
        doSomethingAfterContextRefreshed();
    }

    static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    public static void doSomethingAfterContextRefreshed() {

        ScheduledFuture<?> countdown = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Some message");
            }}, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        while (!countdown.isDone()) {
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(10));
        }
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }

}
```

At the end of the *first* invocation of `doSomethingAfterContextRefreshed` - what do you do? `scheduler.shutdown();`.

At the *second* invocation of `doSomethingAfterContextRefreshed();` what do you do? `scheduler.schedule(....)`.

Is the `scheduler` shutdown at this point in time? What does the documentation of `schedule` says to throw in such cases? You have your answer now.

Comment: Hmm, it is unexpected that ContextRefreshedEvent got triggered more than once during Tomcat startup, but thanks for pointing out the issue.